# Lync SDK Start Audio Video Call with Send only UI Suppression mode

Tags: c#, lync, lync-2013, lync-client-sdk

I am trying to build application for conferencing using Lync SDK in UI Suppression mode, the application is close to the Meet Now feature in lync so that one user will send his Video/Audio to all other users in conversation, my code is:

```
// Add conversation using
_LyncClient.ConversationManager.AddConversation();

// When Conversation added add participants
// User 1 will broadcast video/audio
_Conversation.AddParticipant(_LyncClient.ContactManager.GetContactByUri(user1));
// User 2 and User 3 will only recieve audio video
_Conversation.AddParticipant(_LyncClient.ContactManager.GetContactByUri(user2));
_Conversation.AddParticipant(_LyncClient.ContactManager.GetContactByUri(user3));

// Start the audio call from user1 machine
avModality.BeginConnect(AVCallback);

// When recieve the call in user2, user 3 stop mic using mute
 _Conversation.SelfParticipant.BeginSetMute(true, (ar) =>
    {
        _Conversation.SelfParticipant.EndSetMute(ar);
    }, _Conversation.SelfParticipant);

// and same technique for video
```

It works but i noticed that the performance of the call is affected each time a user enters the conversation and the conversation goes to Hold then Retrive states until user is added.

How Can I start a call in one way only send (not send recive), i tried the following:

```
avModality.BeginConnect(AVCallback, ChannelState.Send);
```

but it didn't work, also i have a look on the [Conversation Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.lync.model.conversation.conversationproperty_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncclnt.aspx), [Moadilty Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.lync.model.conversation.modalityproperty_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncwpf.aspx)
but nothing looks helpful.

the only thing i found related is [avModality.AudioChannel.State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.lync.model.conversation.audiovideo.channelstate_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncclnt%28v=office.15%29.aspx) but i can't find a way to set this property?

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to create a one way video call by starting an audio call from the user who is sending the video and then in ModalityStateChanged calling avModality.VideoChannel.BeginStart once the call was connected.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i am using the same technique, but i noticed that the audio state for the receiver is SendReceive and the video state is Receive.